# Splitting a string of names

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to write a program that will ask a user to input several names, separated by a semi-colon. The names would be entered as lastname,firstname. The program would then print each name in a firstname lastname format on separate lines. So far, my program is:

```
def main():

    names=input("Please enter your list of names: ")
    person=names.split(";")
    xname=person.split(",")
```

This is as far as I got,because there's an error when I try to split on the comma. What am I doing wrong? The output should look like this:

```
Please enter your list of names:  Falcon, Claudio; Ford, Eric; Owen, Megan; Rogers, Josh; St. John, Katherine

You entered:

Claudio Falcon

Eric Ford

Megan Owen

Josh Rogers

Katherine St. John
```

Comment: show the traceback -- cut and paste it into your question along with what you typed for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.split` is a string method that returns a list of strings. So it works fine on splitting the original string of names, but you can't call it on the resulting list (`list` doesn't have a `.split` method, and that really wouldn't make sense). So you need to call `.split` on each of the strings in the list. And to be neat, you should clean up any leading or trailing spaces on the names. Like this:

```
names = "Falcon, Claudio; Ford, Eric; Owen, Megan; Rogers, Josh; St. John, Katherine"
for name in names.split(';'):
    last, first = name.split(',')
    print(first.strip(), last.strip())
```

**output**

```
Claudio Falcon
Eric Ford
Megan Owen
Josh Rogers
Katherine St. John
```

Answer (score 1):

`.split` returns a list, so you are attempting

```
 ["Falcon, Claudio", "Ford, Eric" ...].split(',')
```

Which obviously doesn't work, as `split` is a string method. Try this:

```
full_names = []
for name in names.split("; "):
    last, first = name.split(', ')
    full_names.append(first + " " + last)
```

To give you

```
['Claudio Falcon', 'Eric Ford', 'Megan Owen', 'Josh Rogers', 'Katherine St. John']
```

Comment: There is a space in at least one of the names.

Comment: @Goodies why does that matter?

Comment: @Goodies No problem :)!

Comment: FWIW, my first attempt also used `'; '` and `', '`, but I figured it's better not to make assumptions about how much white space surrounds those separators.

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the whole list instead of each string.  Change it to this:

```
def main():

    names=input("Please enter your list of names: ")
    person=names.split("; ")
    xname=[x.split(", ") for x in person]
```

To print it out, do this:

```
print("\n".join([" ".join(x[::-1]) for x in xname]))
```

Comment: Won't this leave a few stray commas around inside `xname`?

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit: I'm not sure what you mean, but your comment pointed me to something I did wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that you had commas inside the name strings, but you've fixed it now.

Comment: this still has a few stray spaces floating around though. When printing you have two spaces between first and last name, as well as a space before the first name

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit: I'm not sure where you get that.  I have just tested it, and besides the fact that I left out one close parenthesis, it worked just fine.

Comment: Each line looks like `" Katherine  St. John"`. Can't you see the extra whitespace before and between the names?

Comment: Unless you're using your own test input that's different to the OP's that is

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
   names = raw_input("Please enter your list of names:")
    data = names.split(";")
```

data will return you list so process that list to get first name and last name

```
    f_names=[]
    for i in data:
        l_name,f_name= i.split(",")
        f_names.append(f_name+" "+l_name)
    print "you entered \n"+ '\n'.join(p for p in f_names)
```

So this way you can print desired input